# Is there any way to notify the Nifi processor

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi, data-migration

I have a NiFi flow, in which I'm getting data from elasticsearch, after some processing I'm saving flow file in a destination. Once all the flow file is saved I want notify the Merge Process to merge all the data from file into a large csv file. My problem is how I can notify Merge Processor that now all the files are saved and now start merging all the files.

Thanks for the help.. :)

Comment: Did you try Wait-Notify processors? You can add a Wait processor before Merge process and Notify processor after the destination so that Notify will send signals to Wait to release the files after the files are being successfully put to the destination. Need to configure MergeContent/MergeRecords accordingly.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde I don't have any attribute common through all the ff. As Elasticsearch processor generates ff for each page pulled from elastic index with all diff filename. Each ff later splited into individual records present in. I can set identifier of the release signal to the common attribute shared between the original and the generated flow files, and I’m saying that I have to wait for ‘fragment.count’ signal before releasing the original flow. I don't have any common attribute except "es.index" . Is there any way by which I can be sure that all the doc from index have been pulled?

Answer (score 0):

NiFi has a way to use the Wait/Notify processors to notify when the files are saved. What I would suggest is that whichever processor you are using to save the files to have its successful state get sent to the Notify Processor, which could then be used to notify the Wait Processor. The Wait Processor could used with the Merge Processor to merge said files. I know that it is indeed possible to use the Wait/Notify in NiFi for complex actions [Pierre Villard NiFi WorkFlow Wait/Notify](https://pierrevillard.com/2018/06/27/nifi-workflow-monitoring-wait-notify-pattern-with-split-and-merge/)
Although I know that this isnt what you're specifically trying to do here, but this might help you better understand the Wait/Notify a bit better [Wait/Notify Moving Zendesk](https://looker.com/blog/moving-zendesk-data-into-bigquery-with-apache-nifi-wait-notify-processors)

Comment: Thanks for those articles, @Mike But I need to wait till all the doc from elasticsearch pulled, in both the article the wait processor is holding all fragment of single ff (generated from single parent), but I have diff ff and need to wait till all ff (multiple parent ff) is processed.

Comment: Could you wait until 1 FF is done, and then move to the next FF in an if full, move to the next, fashion?